# Battle of Vienna & Morean War : what was Russia's position?

Tags: russia, 17th-century, ottoman-empire, venice

Russia doesn't appear in wikipedia's accounts of the [Morean War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morean_War) or of the preceding [Battle of Vienna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Vienna). I find that mildly suprising. 
Perhaps the reason is that before Peter Russia was less active with her southern frontier?

Question: Is there a recorded Russian position on this conflicts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vienna was besieged in 1683. In the [Treaty of Bakhchisarai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Bakhchisarai), Russia agreed not to fight Ottoman Empire for the time between 1681 and 1701, and actually kept the promise... until 1686 that is. Then it joined the European coalition and started [Russo-Turkish War (1686–1700)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Turkish_War_%281686%E2%80%931700%29), which it won, gaining Azov and Taganrog. Both were lost soon in 1711, Azov re-taken by Turks and Taganrog self-demolished.

Comment: "until 1686 that is" - pure gold. +1 for informative answer

Answer (score 4):

Remember that just a year before Battle of Vienna, tsar [Feodor Alexeyevich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feodor_III_of_Russia) passed away, what resulted with [Moscow Uprising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Uprising_of_1682) of 1682. In result, all the power was gained by [Sophia Alekseyevna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_Alekseyevna), who became the regent of Russia. The future tsar, [Peter the Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_the_Great), was only 10 years old.

Following the uprising, the internal situation of Russia was very unstable, with Prince [Ivan Khovansky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivan_Andreyevich_Khovansky_%28Tararui%29) trying to get the regency for himself. In the fall, after the prince was executed, another rebellion started in Moscow, which even succeeded to take over the [Kremlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Kremlin).

In this situation, foreign politics became less important for a while and any idea of moving the army away from the country in such hard times, surely would be considered as a risk not worth to take.